# Laravel Passport: auth:api returns unauthorised?

Tags: api, laravel-5.6, laravel-passport

I have the following api route:

```
Route::get('/user/get', function(Request $request) {

    return Auth::user();

})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Client application to test the above:

```
   $access_token = 'd3f7333f7602c67e03cab2ab5171e893aeb731af0524d47864fb9d517de46f359a9dc6377195d46e';

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/get';
    $header = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token
    );

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = json_decode($result);
    var_dump($result);
```

var_dump result is always: `Unauthorized.`

I've copied the access_token from the database table and it's neither revoked nor expired and theres only one access_token in the table.

So why is the above not working - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok looks like token inside database table is encrypted or something which is probably why it doesn't work. When I use the token as returned from http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token then it works.